# How to reduce if else jungle from my controller?

Tags: java

I have a java controller class, when ever save action is invoked in any item say Product or coverage or Limit , it calls the controller save method and a parameter is passed. The if logic in the controller checks the argument and call the save method of the appropriate object. The if logic is increasing day by day. Can any one suggest better design pattern?

Code:

```
public class Product {
public void save(PolicyData p){
    //logic here
}
}

public class Coverage {
    public void save(PolicyData p){
        //logic here
    }
}

public class Limit {
    public void save(PolicyData p){
        //logic here
    }
}

public class Controller {

    private Product pr=new Product();
    private Limit lim=new Limit();
    private Coverage cov=new Coverage();


    public void save(PolicyData p,String item){
    if(item.equals("Product")){
        pr.save(p);
    }if(item.equals("Coverage")){
        cov.save(p);
    }if(item.equals("Limit")){
        lim.save(p);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: A "Savable" interface and a `Map<String, Savable>` would work.

Comment: Questions like this one belong here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an interface that has save method
2. Implement the method in your object
3. In your controller create a map to hold objects against the key that you are comparing now in your if

code:

```
public interface Myinterface {
public void save(PolicyData p);
}

public class Product implements Myinterface{
public void save(PolicyData p){
    //logic here
}


public class Controller {


    private static HashMap<String,Myinterface> map=new HashMap<String,Myinterface>();

    public Controller(){
        map.put("Product", new Product());
        map.put("Limit", new Limit());
        map.put("Coverage", new Coverage());
    }

    public void save(PolicyData p,String item){
    Myinterface m=map.get(item);
    m.save(p);
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: There is a bug in constructor, you don't want to put three items with "Product" key.

Answer (score 4):

Create a Saveable interface:

```
public interface Saveable {
    public void save(String p);
}
```

your classes implement the interface, and then create a Map:

```
private Map<String, Saveable> saveMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Fill it with Savable objects and then call the save method based on the String.

```
public enum SaveableType {
    PRODUCT, COVERAGE, LIMIT
}

public class Controller {
    private Product pr = new Product();
    private Limit lim = new Limit();
    private Coverage cov = new Coverage();
    private Map<SaveableType, Saveable> saveableMap = new HashMap<>();

    public Controller() {
        saveableMap.put(SaveableType.PRODUCT, pr);
        saveableMap.put(SaveableType.LIMIT, lim);
        saveableMap.put(SaveableType.COVERAGE, cov);

    }

    // better to use enum for the 2nd parameter not a String
    public void save(PolicyData p, String item) {
        SaveableType saveables = SaveableType.valueOf(item.toUpperCase());
        saveableMap.get(saveables).save(p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really a solution to reduce the if-else jungle. But this might look more "beautiful".

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

So in your case:

```
switch(item) {
    case("Product"): pr.save(item); break;
    // and so on... 
}
```